# How to improve the solution of a double pendulum system

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, precision-and-accuracy

First, the code:

```
(* numerical solution of the double pendulum system in polar coordinates *)
sol = Flatten[{v1, v2, θ1, θ2} /. 
   NDSolve[{v1'[t] == -l^2/
    2 (3 g/l Sin[θ1[t]] + θ1'[t] θ2'[
        t] Sin[θ1[t] - θ2[t]]),
  v2'[t] == -l^2/
    2 (g/l Sin[θ2[t]] + θ1'[t] θ2'[
        t] Sin[θ1[t] - θ2[t]]),
  θ1'[t] == 
   6/(m l^2) (
    2 m v1[t] - 3 Cos[θ1[t] - θ2[t]] m v2[t])/(
    16 - 9 Cos[θ1[t] - θ2[t]]^2),
  θ2'[t] == 
   6/(m l^2) (
    8 m v2[t] - 3 Cos[θ1[t] - θ2[t]] m v1[t])/(
    16 - 9 Cos[θ1[t] - θ2[t]]^2),     
  θ1[0] == π/2, θ2[0] == π/2, 
  v1[0] == v2[0] == 0
  } /. {g -> 9.81, l -> 1, m -> 1}, {v1, 
 v2, θ1, θ2}, {t, 0, 20}
]]

(* cartesian coordinates of pendulum ends *)
x1k[t_, l_] := l Sin[sol[[3]][t]]
y1k[t_, l_] := -l Cos[sol[[3]][t]]
x2k[t_, l_] := l (Sin[sol[[3]][t]] + Sin[sol[[4]][t]])
y2k[t_, l_] := -l (Cos[sol[[3]][t]] + Cos[sol[[4]][t]])

(* corresponding plot *)
ParametricPlot[
Evaluate[{{x1k[t, l], y1k[t, l]}, {x2k[t, l], y2k[t, l]}} /. {l -> 1}], {t, 0, 20}]
```

> [image: double pendulum plot]

As you can see, the function for the position of the second pendulum's end is very inaccurate, so the red curve is jagged instead of smooth. I have tried with specifying various options to `NDSolve`: `AccuracyGoal`, `InterpolationOrder`, `MaxStepFraction`, `PrecisionGoal`, but neither seemed to help.

Comment: The problem is with plotting, not `NDSolve`.  Try setting the options `PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 8` on `ParametricPlot`.

Comment: Right, this solves it. Any idea why it doesn't plot smooth functions by default?

Comment: Because `MaxRecursion` limits how much effort the plotting function may put into making it smooth.  Some functions would take a very long time to make smooth.

Comment: The number of points that will be plotted is limited for performance reasons, as in all other systems. Mathematica actually has an advantage here because it does adaptive plotting. First it divides the `{t,0,20}` interval into `PlotPoints` number of *equal* parts and computes the function at each point. Many other systems will do only this much, and will typically give you some jaggedness. But Mathematica will look at each segment pair and if their angle is large enough (i.e. if they look jagged), it will subdivide them to make the plot smoother. Then it repeats this up to MaxRecursion times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem has to do with the sample points used to contruct the plot, and not with `NDSolve`.  *Mathematica* automatically subdivides segments when the angle is greater than some limit, but it will do so only `MaxRecursion` times.  One can increase `PlotPoints` to increase the number of initial sample points and increase `MaxRecursion` to let *Mathematica* subdivide further where needed.

```
ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate[{{x1k[t, l], y1k[t, l]}, {x2k[t, l], y2k[t, l]}} /. {l -> 1}],
    {t, 0, 20}, PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 8]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The angles one sees in the plot in the question usually result from a large velocity, or in other words from a large change in arclength for a given change in parameter `t`.

One can see that is the case here from the plot of the speed:

```
Plot[Evaluate @ Norm @ {D[x2k[t, 1], t], D[y2k[t, 1], t]}, {t, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Another approach, perhaps not needed here, is to reparametrize by arclength.  Then the velocity will be constant.  If the curve is not very long, then the default plotting options will probably produce a smooth graph.

For this problem the speed is zero at `t == 0`, which produces a singularity if we use the standard initial value `t[0] == 0`.  So instead we integrate the speed over a short interval to get a nonzero initial value.

```
invarclength = Quiet @ NDSolveValue[
   {t'[s] == 1/Norm @ {Derivative[1, 0][x2k][t[s], 1], Derivative[1, 0][y2k][t[s], 1]},
    t[NIntegrate[Norm @ {Derivative[1, 0][x2k][t, 1], Derivative[1, 0][y2k][t, 1]},
                 {t, 0, 10^-16}]] == 10^-16,
    WhenEvent[t[s] == 20, "StopIntegration"]},
   t, {s, 0, Infinity}]

ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate[{{x1k[#, 1], y1k[#, 1]}, {x2k[#, 1], y2k[#, 1]}} &@ invarclength[s]], 
 Evaluate @ {s, Sequence @@ First @ invarclength["Domain"]}]
```

It produces a plot similar to the one above, but of about 1/3 the `ByteCount`.

Comment: @Phonon If `ImageSize` is `Automatic`, then image sizes are automatically scaled in certain contexts.  You could use `GraphicsRow[{##}] &` instead of `Row`.  Or use the `ImageSize` option. Or both.

Comment: @Phonon If you like, but, quite sincerely, your gratitude is enough of a reward. :)